# error con el servidor de sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Recién he instaldo VS 2015 Profesional. Al crear un nuevo webProject y solamente compilarlo (sin hacer ningún cambio en el código), cuando intente registrame me salio el siguiente error

> `Server Error in '/' Application.`
>
> The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Source Error:
>
> `Line 153: { Line 154: var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email }; Line 155: var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password); Line 156: if (result.Succeeded) Line 157: {`
>
> `Source File: c:\users****\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication5\WebApplication5\Controllers\AccountController.cs Line: 155`
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> `[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]`

Luego he descargo un proyecto de un repositorio de github, lo he compilado (sin tocar el còdigo) y al seguir un link done la app debía conectar con la base de datos me ha lanzado una excepción y luego un error en el navegador:

> `Server Error in '/' Application.`
>   El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado

Source Error:

> Line 53:         {
>   Line 54:             var filtered = id != null && id != 0;
>   Line 55:             var query = filtered ? service.GetAll x.BlogId == id) : service.GetAll();
>   Line 56:             if (filtered)
>   Line 57:                 TempData["message"] = "Filtered list";
>
> `Source File: D:\SampleMvcWebApp\SampleWebApp\Controllers\PostsController.cs    Line: 55`

Creo que debo tener algo mal en alguna configuración o que me falta alguna librería. Si alguien me puede ayudar le estaré muy agradecido

Answer (score 0):

El problema es de conexión entre el servidor y la red, te sugiero que analices los siguientes aspectos:

- Configuración del firewall desde el servidor web al servidor de la base de datos.
- errores en la cadena de conexión
- habilitar el protocolo apropiado de tuberías / tcp-ip

Intenta conectarte al servidor sql con el servidor de administración sql en el sistema en el que está instalado el servidor sql y trabaje desde allí. 
Presta atención a la información en los registros de error.

**Pd: ¿Te aseguraste que si estuviese corriendo el servicio de SQL?**